# Credit Card Company asking for personal information and wont let me close my account. What can i do?

Tags: credit-card

I have had an account with Credit One Bank for 7 months now. Recently this week they suspended my account to their online web portal and told me i have to send a copy of my photo ID through the mail which will take 7-10 days. Upon further research it seems they are running a huge scam over at credit one where they have you send in documents that are not normally sent to a credit card company and sold to identity thief's.

What should i do in this situation?

Comment: `that are not normally sent to a credit card company` Like what documents ?

Comment: Where did you read that they are running a scam?

Comment: The point of photo ID is to compare the photo to the person presenting it. Taking it through the mail seems a bit pointless.

Comment: How did you find out that your portal access is suspended? Was it a letter or an email, or a message when you logged on? Have you actually tried to log on to your online portal? I suspect you are being scammed, but not by Credit One.

Comment: "Upon further research it seems they are running a huge scam over at credit one where they have you send in documents that are not normally sent to a credit card company and sold to identity thief's." That's a pretty huge accusation.

Comment: The login portal showed my login was suspended. My card was frozen by credit one and when i called them they said i had to send in a copy of my ID through the mail because they do not accept documents through email. I then proceeded to research this on some credit card forums and found that the workers at the company ask for personal information and sell it to people associated with identity theft. One of the main sites pushing the scam narrative was on consumeraffiar.com where there are over 1k reviews on the subject.

Comment: The same information can be found on the BBB website as well.

Answer (score 1):

> Recently this week they suspended my account to their online web portal and told me i have to send a copy of my photo ID through the mail which will take 7-10 days.

Verify that the communication you have got is from Credit One. This best way to do is write to them or call them using the number provided in the website. If you were asked via email or phone, rule out spoofing by verifying this info.

> Upon further research it seems they are running a huge scam over at credit one where they have you send in documents that are not normally sent to a credit card company and sold to identity thief's.

Credit One may have lousy reviews and may not be the best bank as per reviews. However to make an assumption that Bank would indulge is something like this maybe incorrect. They are governed by banking norms. What is still possible is that quite a few of verification / data collection tasks are outsourced and they may not be reliable.

> What should i do in this situation?

- Verify that the request is legit by contacting them on published numbers / email ID's.
- If you are asked to send documents via mail; ensure that you mark these with words like "For Credit One, to validate KYC on existing account ending with XXXX1234. Dated today."
- The above is a good practise, it makes it difficult for someone to use this identity documents for something else. If it goes in wrong hands, it gives them an indication that you are careful with you identify and monitor; hence they will move to some other easy target.

Comment: Better yet, call them using the number on the back of your card.